# How to know the last launch time of an app

Tags: android

Hi After doing lots of Search , I could not find the answer of a question, that seems somewhat simple.

I have multiple apps installed on device. Is there any way of finding the last launching date of all apps?

Comment: not that simple, since because apps in background are not necessarily stopped, opening an app does not always means starting it.

Comment: To clarify, you want to know when was the last the last time a bunch of [possibly your] apps were brought to foreground?

Answer (score 2):

You could put the time and date in an SharedPref when the app opens.
Then, the next time you open the app the app reads the SharedPref and displays it.

Something like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    SharedPreferences sp = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String lastLaunch = sp.getString("launch", "First launch!");

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("launch", c.getTime().toString());
    editor.commit();
}
```

The String lastLaunch is the last time it launched! If it's the first time the string is: "First launch!"

I hope that i have helped you a little bit :)

Comment: If it's the first time, the value won't even be present in the Shared prefs

Comment: @jmm Yes, that's true but then it will take the basic value: "First launch!". The second parameter in sp.getString(id, basic value);

Comment: This isn't the query he's looking for.

Comment: I want to write a code, which will display last start time of all apps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements from the comments above, I'm providing a method to share the launch times between a bunch of our apps using `SharedPreferences`.

Firstly, we need to allow our apps to share local storage so they can access preference data. For this, we use the `sharedUserId` property in the app manifest. This can be your own unique string and each of the apps that share the space must have this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example.com.myapp"
    android:sharedUserId="string.user.id.here">

    ...

</manifest>
```

Secondly, we use the `Application` class to determine when the app comes to the foreground and when it does, write the timestamp in `Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY` mode to share between our apps:

```
public class MyApp extends Application implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    private boolean appInBg;
    private int TIMEOUT = 5000;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed() {
        if (appInBg) {
            writeToPref();
        } else {
            mHandler.cancelCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused() {
        mHanlder.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                appInBg = true;
            }

        }, TIMEOUT);
    }

    ...


    private void writeToPref() {
         SharedPreferences prefs = myContext.getSharedPreferences("run_prefs", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
         prefs.edit().putInt("last_run", System.currentTimeMillis()).apply();
    }
}
```

Here, we allow a buffer time of 5 seconds to switch between screens. This should be adequate in most cases.

Finally, we can read the written `SharedPreference` value as follows:

```
Context context = createPackageContext("example.com.myapp", 0);
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("run_prefs", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
int lastLaunch = pref.getString("last_run", System.currentTimeMillis());
// Similarly, for other apps.
```

Hope this solves your issue.